# How to get validation errors from specific model when working with transactions?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Right not i'm using code like this:

```
return Sequelize
    .transaction((t) => {
            return userModel
                .update(req.body.user, {where: {userId: userModel.id}, transaction: t})
                .then((u) => Passport.upsert(_.extend(req.body.passport, {userId: u.id}), {transaction: t}))
        })
        .then(() => res.flash('success', 'Save!'))
        .catch(Sequelize.ValidationError, (err) => {
             res.flash('danger', 'Error!');
             console.log('Errors:', err);
        });
```

When i get error at 'catch', instance of ValidationError don't have a reference to model. As a result i don't know who has errors Passport or User.